# Updating SQLite Database

Tags: android, android-layout, sqlite

When my first activity loads the database gets created in the OnCreate(). Then in the next activity when i delete few rows from a table and come back to the first activity again all the database gets created with all records in it. I want that the database to show me the updated table records and not execute the create & inserting into the tables again...

Comment: Please explain your problem in more details. How are you deleting the rows, and what are you doing to refresh the contents of your first activity.

Comment: Im deleting the row by sql statement. Im going to the main activity as it is my home page..

Comment: Do you reload the list from the database?

Comment: Do you use SQLiteOpenHelper? It manages the creation of tables, you shouldn't have such a problem using it

Comment: I donot want it to execute the creation of tables & inserting of record when the main activity gets loaded when the back button is pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning to create your database first and to incrementally modify it, you can use `SharedPreferences` and somewhere in your ressources you can have a number representing the version of your application, so that it will get called only if you increment this number.

```
// In your onCreate function

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myoptions", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int resourceVersion = //Gets the new version from the resources, for example XML
int applicationVersion = prefs.getInt("APPLICATION_VERSION", 0);
if(applicationVersion < resourceVersion ) {
  // Create or update your database here
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("myoptions", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
  editor.putInt("APPLICATION_VERSION", resourceVersion );
  editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think before creating/inserting values in Database in the first activity you are not checking if it already exist or not, so each time you enter the first activity your database rebuilds. So, check if database already exists before creating it with following approach:

---

Open your database in try block with path of the databse like:

```
try{
   SQLiteDatabase   dbe = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/bangla.rana.fahim/databases/dictionary", null,0);
            Log.d("opendb","EXIST");
            dbe.close();
            }
```

if an exception occurs then database doesn't exit so create it:

```
catch(SQLiteException e){
                Log.d("opendb","NOT EXIST");

            SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("dictionary", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LIST(wlist varchar);");

                    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO LIST VALUES('খবর');");
                    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO LIST VALUES('কবর');"); //whatever you want
                 db.close();
}
```

that's it you are done :)